# How to combine CUBE and ROLLUP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a query with an important `GROUP BY` aggregation. Here is a simplified schema ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e941a/1/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE [data] (
    [year] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [month] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [country] [varchar] (32) NOT NULL ,
    [state] [varchar]   (32),
    [city] [varchar]  (32) NOT NULL ,
    [federation] [varchar]  (32) NOT NULL ,
    [id] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [price] [int] NOT NULL );

INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFJ', 1, 23)
INSERT data values(2013, 2, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFV', 2, 212)
INSERT data values(2012, 1, 'USA', 'CA', 'Paris', 'FFV', 3, 23)
INSERT data values(2013, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFV', 4, 273)
INSERT data values(2012, 9, 'USA', 'OR', 'Lake Oswego', 'FFV', 5, 743)
INSERT data values(2012, 11, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFJ', 6, 3)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFV', 7, 231)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'USA', 'CA', 'St Monica', 'FFV', 8, 41)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFV', 9, 96)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Vire', 'FFJ', 10, 23)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Paris', 'FFV', 11, 58)
INSERT data values(2012, 12, 'France', NULL, 'Nice', 'FFV', 12, 773)
```

I group by columns `year, month, country, state, federation, city`.

I use the `ROLLUP` operator because I need to get totals on multiple levels. But I would also like to apply `CUBE` to two of the columns, `country` (a geographical attribute) and `federation` (and organizational attribute).

If I just `CUBE` in my query, I get much more output than I need. (I really don't need to apply `CUBE` to all my GROUP BY columns.)

Does a workaround exist?

Comment: could you give some sample data !to test ?

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 Here a simplified Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e941a/1/0

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114 The two fields I want to CUBE is `Country` (a geographic attribut) and `federation` (an organizationnal attribut)

Comment: I've edited your question to make the problem look clearer. Please review and feel free to correct as necessary.

Comment: You can try to use only `CUBE` and filter out the unwanted aggregation using the `GROUPING` function, but Andriy M solution is way more readable

Comment: @Serpiton Good idea, I forgot that I could use `WHERE` clause. But I wonder if *cubing* a lot of unwanted aggregation is good for performance...

Comment: @Fractaliste The only way to know is to test it, but there will be a metric ton of condition to write, and I think that the query from the answer has already good performances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 supports only the non-ISO-compliant `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` and `GROUP BY ... WITH CUBE`, two pieces of syntax that does not offer much flexibility. You can have only a full rollup/cube with those, no variations or combinations.

However, a workaround in your particular case might not be too cumbersome. The ROLLUP would give you the following groupings:

```
year, month, country, state, federation, city
year, month, country, state, federation
year, month, country, state
year, month, country
year, month
year
()  -- grand total
```

And my understanding of what you want instead is this:

```
year, month, country, state, federation, city
year, month, country, state, federation
year, month, country, state
year, month, country, federation
year, month, country
year, month
year
()
```

Apparently you need to add just one more grouping subset to the ROLLUP output, namely this one:

```
year, month, country, federation
```

You could just calculate it in a separate SELECT and combine the results with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.data
GROUP BY
  year, month, country, state, federation, city
  WITH ROLLUP

UNION ALL

SELECT ...
FROM dbo.data
GROUP BY
  year, month, country, federation
;
```

Comment: In the end I partially follow your idea, I perform `UNION` of grouped result sets, but with no `ROLLUP`(I do them manually, because I also need to calculate some mathematics function on results from `ROLLUP`).